# Print symmetric matrix in fewer iterations than n*m

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Is there a way to print symmetric matrix in less amount of iterations than n*m.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; ++j) {
        System.out.print(i * j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is symmetric, it has to be quadratic, meaning `m == n`. Then it has `m*(m+1)/2` independent elements. That's the number of elements you need to access and probably what you mean by number of iterations. If you have a `print` function that allows you to specify the position of the printed element on your screen, you can print two elements (i,j and j,i) in one iteration.

However, if you use `System.out.print` this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Start `j` at `i`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j <= m; ++j) {
        System.out.print(i * j + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
 }
```

Only works when `n == m` and this doesn't pad the front of the shorter rows

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to print symmetric matrix in less amount of iterations than n*m.

Printing with `system.out.println()` with lesser than `n*m` is *not possible*. However if you are asking about updating the matrix, it is *possible*.

If the matrix is symmetric, half of the matrix will look at the other half (diagonally), hence you only need to iterate through half the matrix. By updating 2 elements concurrently (first & last, followed for first+1, last-1..and so on), you will get a complete symmetric matrix updated.

If you want to print out the matrix, then obviously you have to iterate through every element in the matrix.

**For example:**

```
int r = 7;
int c = 7;

int[][] matrix = new int[r][c];
for(int x=0; x<=r; x++)
    for(int y=0; y<r-x; y++){
        matrix[x][y] = Math.min(x, y);         //Update 1st diagonal half of the matrix
        matrix[r-x-1][c-y-1] = matrix[x][y];   //Update the next half (follow 1st half) 
    }
```

**Matrix value:**

```
0000000
0111110
0122210
0123210
0122210
0111110
0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible : simply use any of the algorithms provided here but instead of filling up a matrix concatene results to R strings.
At the end print the R strings.

this gives you (c*r)/2 + r iterations.

Pseudo-code :

```
int rows = 7; int cols = 7;

List<String> previous = new List<String>(rows);

for(int x=0; x<=rows; x++) {
    // if beginning of row has already been calculated then print it out
    if ( previous[y] != null) System.out.print(previous);

    // then start at X to calculate the rest of the row
    for(int y=x; y<=cols; y++){ 
        System.out.print(x*y);         
        previous[y] += " " + x*y;
    }
}
```